# Maven Plugin documentation Goals with a read more-link?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, doclet

Is there a way to shorten the text which is shown on the Maven plugin documentation Page under the point Usage?

I wrote a long Mojo-description and i do not wan't to show it all on the first usage page.

So is there a way to add something like a "Read more" link or simple shorten the displayed text ?

Update:
 I added a table to the class-description and I do not want to show this table on the Usage-Page.

Comment: Can you give an example? Cause the usage page is written by the author of the plugin?

Comment: I'm the author of the plugin